# Convert JSON to different looking CSV in Java

Tags: java, json, csv

I need to write a code which would convert JSON file to CSV. The problem is in a format that the CSV file should look like.

Input json:

```
{
   "strings":{
      "1level1":{
         "1level2":{
            "1label1":"1value1",
            "1label2":"1value2"
         }
      },
      "2level1":{
         "2level2":{
            "2level3":{
               "2label1":"2value1"
            },
            "2label2":"2value2"
         }
      }
   }
}
```

And this is expected csv file for this json:

```
Keys,Default
1level1.1level2.1label1,1value1
1level1.1level2.1label2,1value2
2level1.2level2.2level3.2label1,2value1
2level1.2level2.2label2,2value2
```

I was trying to go through JSON file using recursion but this didn't work for me because of rewriting JSON object on each iteration and code was working only till the first value. Are there any suggestions about how can it be done?

Note: have tried to use different JSON libraries, so for now can be used any of them

UPDATE #1:
Non-working code example I was trying to use to go through JSON tree:

```
public static void jsonToCsv() throws JSONException {
    InputStream is = MainClass.class.getResourceAsStream("/fromJson.json");
    JSONTokener jsonTokener = new JSONTokener(is);

    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(jsonTokener);
    stepInto(jsonObject);
}

private static void stepInto(JSONObject jsonObject) {
    JSONObject object = jsonObject;
    try {
        Set < String > keySet = object.keySet();
        for (String key: keySet) {
            object = object.getJSONObject(key);
            stepInto(object);
        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Set < String > keySet = object.keySet();
        for (String key: keySet) {
            System.out.println(object.get(key));
        }

        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

UPDATE #2:
Another issue is that I will never know the names of the JSON object and count of child objects (update JSON and CSV examples as well to make the image more clear). All that is known, that it will always start with **strings** object.

Library used:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.json</groupId>
    <artifactId>json</artifactId>
    <version>20180813</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: why don't you post your recursive solution and then we can help you find the problem? I am pretty sure you don't need any fancy json libraries for that. Any valid JSON is simply a `map` with key-value pairs. You should be able to traverse that map level by level and construct the CSV lines.

Comment: @GameDroids I have added code I have tried to use (it is not good, I know) and added some notes to make image more clear. Please, take a look once again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So found a solution by myself:

```
public static void jsonToCsv() throws JSONException, IOException {
    InputStream is = MainClass.class.getResourceAsStream("/fromJson.json");
    JSONTokener jsonTokener = new JSONTokener(is);

    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(jsonTokener).getJSONObject("strings");
    builder = new StringBuilder();

    while (!jsonObject.isEmpty()) {
        stepInto(jsonObject);
    }

    String[] lines = builder.toString().split("\n"); // builder lines are in reverse order from expected so this array is used to reverse them

    FileWriter csvWriter = new FileWriter("src/main/resources/toCsv.csv");
    csvWriter.append("Keys,Default (en_US)\n");

    for (int i = lines.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        csvWriter.append(lines[i]).append("\n");
    }

    csvWriter.flush();
    csvWriter.close();
}


private static void stepInto(JSONObject jsonObject) {
    for (String key: jsonObject.keySet()) {
        Object object = jsonObject.get(key);
        if (object instanceof JSONObject) {
            builder.append(key).append(".");
            stepInto(jsonObject.getJSONObject(key));
        } else {
            builder.append(key).append(",").append(object).append("\n");
            jsonObject.remove(key);
            break;
        }

        if (jsonObject.getJSONObject(key).isEmpty()) {
            jsonObject.remove(key);
        }
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: neat solution! If I may: you are running your methods in a `static` environment and that is fine. But since your `StringBuilder` is global and static, your program only has one single instance of that builder - so when you execute the function multiple times simultaneously it will try reading (maybe) different JSONs into different CSV with only one StringBuilder. **Idea:** pass a local StringBuilder to your `stepInto` method. Your `jsonToCsv` method holds and creates the instance of the SB and passes it to `stepInto` (you just pass it along with the recursive calls). What do you thing?

Comment: @GameDroids This code was just made in separate project to make it easier to develop. When I will move it to the main project I will do that right how you said :) But thank you for advice!

Answer (score 0):

I think you just missed keeping track of your result, otherwise it looks good.

Let's say your result is a simple string. Then you have to concatenate all keys while traversing the json object until you reach a primitive value (like a number or a string).

**(I am writing this out of my head, so please forgive me for incorrect syntax)**

```
private static String stepInto(JSONObject jsonObject) {  // we change "void" to "String" so we can record the results of each recursive "stepInto" call
    //JSONObject object = jsonObject;                    // we don't need that. Both variables are the same object
    String result ="";
    try {
        for (String key: jsonObject.keySet()) {          // shorter version
            Object object = jsonObject.get(key);         // Attention! we get a simple Java Object
            if(object instanceof JSONObject){
               result+= key+"."+stepInto(jsonObject.getJSONObject(key));  // the recursive call, returning all keys concatenated to "level1.level2.level3" until we reach a primitive value
            }
            if(object instanceof JSONArray){
               result+= key+", "+ ...                      // notice how we use the csv separator (comma) here, because we reached a value. For you to decide how you want to represent arrays
            }
            result+= key +", "+ object +"\n";                    // here I am not sure. It may well be that you need to check if object is a String an Integer, Float or anything.
        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {        
        for (String key: jsonObject.keySet()) {
            System.out.println(object.get(key));
        }
        e.printStackTrace();
        result+= "\n";                                        // I added this fallback so your program can terminate even when an error occurs.
    } 
    return result;  // sorry, I forgot to accumulate all results and return them. So now we have only one actual "return" statement that will terminate the call and return all results.

}
```

As you can see, I didn't change much of your original method. The only difference is that now we keep track of the keys (`"level1.level2..."`) for each recursive call.

**EDIT**

I added a `+"\n";` so everytime we reach a value so we can terminate that "line".

**AND** more importantly, instead of returning everytime, I add the result of each call to a string, so we continue looping over the keys and concatenate all results. Each call of the method will return only once all keys are looped over. (sorry that missed that)

In your calling method you could print out the result, something like that:

```
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(jsonTokener);
String result = stepInto(jsonObject);
System.out.println(result);
```

Comment: The issue is that in such case it will go only through the first tree ("1level1.1level2...") but will ignore another one ("2level1.2level2..."), won't it?

Comment: please see my edit. I forgot that the method would terminate at the first value. Now it continues the loop and should traverse the whole object

Comment: Output of this code:
`strings.2level1.2level2.2label2.2value2`
`2level3.2label1.2value1`
`2level3.{"2label1":"2value1"}`
`2level2.{"2label2":"2value2","2level3":{"2label1":"2value1"}}`
`2level1.{"2level2":{"2label2":"2value2","2level3":{"2label1":"2value1"}}}`
`1level1.1level2.1label2.1value2`
`1label1.1value1`
`1level2.{"1label2":"1value2","1label1":"1value1"}`
`1level1.{"1level2":{"1label2":"1value2","1label1":"1value1"}}`
`strings.{"2level1":{"2level2":{"2label2":"2value2","2level3":{"2label1":"2value1"}}},"1level1":{"1level2":{"1label2":"1value2","1label1":"1value1"}}}`

Comment: Creating StringBuilder in main method and passing it as parameter to stepInto helps to avoid such output but still haven't found the way how to let the code go through full tree (each row would start with `strings.` which can be easily replaced later. For now I reached such output using your suggestion with StringBuilder:
`strings.2level1.2level2.2label2,2value2`
`2level3.2label1,2value1`
`1level1.1level2.1label2,1value2`
`1label1,1value1`

Comment: Have found a solution and posted it. You can check if you're interested. Thank you anyway!